# How WMI can execute command remotely?

Tags: active-directory, wmi

I want to do gpupdate remotely immediately when finishing group policy on server,is there any method to batch run the command "gpupdate /force" on remote pc ? I've used powershell to complete but there's problem that  should run "Enable-PSRemoting" on remote pc and choice All item to create listener.So I want to find is there any method to run command remotely? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI or psexec to run the command, but keep in mind that the user portion will run for the user executing the command, not the logged in user.  If you need that, it gets complicated.  Here you could write a program that impersonates the logged in user, and start that via psexec using -s swith, which executes the command as system. System has the permissions to imersonate per default.